# Удаление определенного текста с переносом строк

Tags: php

У нас есть текст. Например, такой:

Абзац1: слово, слово, слово, слово, слово, слово.

Абзац2: слово, слово, слово, слово, слово, слово.

Абзац3: слово, слово, слово, слово, слово, слово.

Если мы спарсим первые 20 слов и после них поставим "привет" с помощью такого кода:

```
$text = "Текст, который нужно разделить. Здесь у нас много-много абзацев.";
$words = preg_split("/[\s\n\r]+/", $text, 21); 
    $count = 20;
    for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++){
    $a .= ($words[$i].' ');
    }
$a .= "привет";
    $a = strtr($a, array($text => $a));
    echo $a;
```

В итоге ничего не заменяется, если абзацев несколько. Как сделать, чтобы заменялось, даже если несколько абзацев?

**Кратко:**
Нужно ставить после 20 первых слов, слово "привет" - вне зависимости от того, есть ли в тексте переносы строк или пробелы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asen, вместо wordwrap лучше использовать substr_replace, т.к. мне нужно вставлять всего 1 раз. Проблема решена. Вопрос можно закрыть. Нашел совсем другой способ, этот код мне нужен был для работы с CMS Wordpress. Там уже есть готовое решение:

```
the_excerpt();
```

Answer (score 0):

Как я понял, задача состоит в том, что надо заменить текст, так?
Так попробуй найти нужный тебе текст на странице с помощью "strpos()"
и реплейсни его на '' . Это если я правильно понял задачу, если нет, то надо конкретизировать...

Comment: Добавил краткое описание. Думаю, самое понятное.

Comment: Продублирую.
Кратко: Нужно ставить после 20 первых слов, слово "привет" - вне зависимости от того, есть ли в тексте переносы строк или пробелы.

Comment: За помощь могу заплатить. Называйте свою цену.

Comment: Если считать слова по пробелам, то так пойдет?

Comment: Как иначе то? Можно конечно игнорировать предлоги.

Comment: Asen, а если там будет перенос строки (до 20 слова), то как на это прореагирует скрипт?

Comment: @nick777, можно сделать так, что если перевод строки встретился ранее, то после 20 слов он вставляться не будет....а вообще, если вам надо что-либо вставлять после определенного количества символов, то просто юзайте "wordwrap()":
$newtext = wordwrap($text, 20, "<br />\n"); // после каждых 20 
                                        //символов вставляет перевод =)